# Trying to get and edit article

Tags: php, sql

How should look the right code for pick up and edit article? I'm trying to do it but still getting  mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, string given in.

```
 <?php
 $db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "maturita");
 if(isset($_GET['edit_art']))
 {
    $sql="SELECT * FROM articles WHERE id_art='{$_GET['id_edit']}'";
    $query=mysqli_query($db, $sql);

    while($log = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)):
        $subject = $log["subject"];
        $text = $log["text"];

?>
<div class="content2">
<div class="content title1">
Edit Article
</div>
<div class="content backgrounded">
<form action="#" method="post">        
<table>
    <tr>
    <td>Subject: </td><td><input class="subject form form3" type="text" name="subject"><?php $subject; ?></input></td>
    </tr>
    <td>Text: </td><td><textarea name="text" rows="5" cols="51"><?php echo $text; ?></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><input type="submit" class="button button5" name="submit" value="Submit"/></td>
    </tr>
   </table>   
</form>
</div>
</div>
<?php endwhile;}?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should simply use `mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)` instead of `mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)`.

Please **do not** insert contents from `$_GET`, `$_POST` or `$_REQUEST` directly to a SQL statement, use prepared statements with placeholders instead.

Btw. the code part `"SELECT * FROM articles WHERE id_art='{$_GET['id_edit']}'"` is correct and will add single qoutes only if they are submitted in the GET parameter. This will also happen with `WHERE id_art='" . $_GET['id_edit'] . "'";`. For further information read the PHP manual: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double